# data to export one workbook to another workbook

Tags: vba

I want to export data from one workbook to another ............Data to export from source workbook (name of source workbook should be written in cell "M1") and worksheet "SALARY"  from range column E4 to S TO destination workbook (name of destination workbook should be written in "N11") and worksheet "SALARY DETAIL" range column A2 to O.  And I want to export data if column “US” has value more than zero.

```
Sub Salary() 
Name = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("24Q INPUT DATA").Range("M1").Value 
Set src = Workbooks(Name).Sheets(6) 
x = Workbooks(Name).Sheets(6).Range("N11").Value 

Set des = Workbooks(x).Sheets(4) 
' desitination file 
  L2 = src.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 

If WorksheetFunction.Sum(src.Columns("US")) > 0 Then 
   src.Range("UJ12:ZB" & L2).Copy 
   des.Range("A3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 
End If 
Set src = Nothing 
Set des = Nothing 

End Sub
```

Right now, data is exporting but all data is exporting even column "US" has zero.

Comment: I tried to improve your formatting. Make sure it's correct. When pasting in your code, use the Code Blocks {} to allow for correct sytnax.

Comment: Sir, Please do it on your own........as I have not much of knowledge about vba. So what you do to correct this code will help me

Comment: Sir, Please help me

Comment: I just meant the formatting of it. Meaning I put new lines in the correct place.

Comment: Off course sir, what you are saying is correct...but because I have not much knowledge about VBA code.......please i need above the code to be corrected.

Comment: Do you want to only import the cells in column US where the individual value is not zero?

Comment: Sir, what I mean to say if the column US from source file has value more than zero then only that row will be exported to destination sheet.